# Set Filemaker Pro layout to sort on leaving record

Tags: filemaker

Actually, I want to unset it.

I'm fixing up an FMP database that's been around for years.  Part of it is a layout that shows a table of scheduled events.  Whenever I move from one record to another, it automatically sorts on two fields: StartDate and StartTime.  I don't want it to do that anymore, but I can't find it to remove it.

I don't think it's a script.  There is a SORT script in the database, but removing it did not stop the auto-sort behavior.

Comment: this may sound silly but how do you know it is Sorting on those two fields?  Whats your evidence?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the auto-sorts use whatever the last sort criteria were, and StartDate/StartTime is the only sort we do on this table.  I think I confirmed it by sorting on another field, and then running my script again.  Since I wasn't changing the data in field I sorted by, the record stayed where it was.

Answer (score 1):

Check the SCRIPT TRIGGERS for the fields, i think you will find in "OnObjectsave" it calls script.

right click on the field > set script triggers

Comment: I checked each field in the layout, and none of them has a script trigger set.  As I said above, I'm pretty sure this is based on the last sort performed.  To keep it from messing with my applescript (the record number was changing while the script was filling fields), I guess I'm going to have to add a new position field, and then sort on that.

Comment: Actually, better yet; I originally set the start_date field to a very early date to ensure that my record stays at record 1 while I populate the rest of the fields.  When I'm all done, I set the start_date to the correct date, and the populated record drops down to the correct row.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a Script Trigger may be running on the layout. To find out:

> In Layout mode, navigate to LAYOUTS > LAYOUT SETUP... 
>   and then click the SCRIPT TRIGGERS tab.  Layout script
>   triggers can only be configured one layout at a time.

More information on script triggers can be found here: http://help.filemaker.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/7465

Comment: I thought this was promising, but there are no script triggers set there, either. As I said earlier, there is only one script in the database that would do the sort, and removing it did not help.  After further exploration, I'm pretty sure that FMP is doing this on it's own.  If I do a sort on a field other than the date and time, then changing the date does not cause a resort.  I found some posts at Filemaker asking them to change that behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Is this data from a related file/table? There might a "sort" criteria be defined in the relation.

Comment: Hi Kevin, did that work, or was this too unspecific? I think I'm not able to insert a screenshot, with my few "points"...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have this nagging problem also.  The solution is found in Filemaker Help, topic = Sort, item = Options for Sorting Records.  See next to last item in their instruction table (FM-12).

The setting causing automatic sorting is found in the Sort definition dialog that defines sort order for your layout.  Somewhere in your script you defined a sort for your layout. OR, when creating the layout, you defined a sort order for it.  Whichever, you need to find and open the Sort dialog box.  Unselect "Keep records in Sorted Order."   Otherwise, Filemaker will re-sort automatically.

Hope this helps.